# emmet custom snippets with variables

Tags: django-templates, code-snippets, emmet

I need generate my custom tag "django template tag"
I want to create correct tag for snippet

after

```
bdlock{foo}
```

get

```
{% block foo %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I have that

```
{
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
            "dblock": "{\\{% block change_name %\\}\n ${1} \t\n\\{% endblock change_name %\\}}"
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm trying find the way how to set variable inside tag for change "change_name" on what I need
like "block content" or block "block header" or what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `${child}` placeholder in place where children should be outputted. In you example, `{text}` is a text child of parent element

Comment: this does not resolve the issue

Comment: Please fill an issue here: http://github.com/emmetio/emmet/